# Repeating Speaker popping on Lenovo Slim 7(Ryzen7)

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I've been having some issues with Unbuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my Lenovo Slim 7 (14ARE05) but the one that is really bothering me is this speaker issue I've been dealing with since installing Unbuntu. The issue is there is a constant repeating popping noise with no breaks in between them. Seems like it is the volume adjusting sound continually playing over and over again when the speakers are on the sound goes away when the speakers are muted.

This issue causes bluetooth devices to not connect for some reason and the settings menu will stop responding if I try and pair headphones or keyboards to it. This issue seems to come and go. When I first installed Ubuntu it was present and it eventually went away on its own after multiple reboots, which is no longer working.

I hope its allowed to add Gdrive video, if not please let me know what I can use to upload this video to give an accurate description of what I am dealing with.

I apologize in advanced for my cat being dramatic toward the end of the 10sec video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/100O8PK2xKiPe3DrcEn_V_INdhG6sKW0g/view?usp=sharing

Quick edit: I forgot to mention that this laptop dual boots Win10 if that is of any importance. The issue is not present on Win10.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be resolved by making an edit to your `alsa-base.conf` file. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal
1. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` with `sudo` using your preferred editor
2. Add the following line to the end:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel index=1
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Reboot the machine

This will probably change the name of your sound device to "HD-Audio Generic", but it will resolve the sound that you're hearing. If instead you see "Dummy Output", restart PulseAudio with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: I added the options snd-hda-intel index=1 to the end of the file and restarted. doesn't seem to work. It did change my sound device to HD-Audio Generic.  I added that line right below this line "# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2" Should I be removing this line aswell?

Comment: I marked this as solving my issue. It wasn't working yesterday to fix the sound issue but today the sound doesn't seem to be occurring. I appreciate the help!